# How to transfer flowfiles in NiFi using NiFi API?

Tags: rest, apache-nifi

I want to use NiFi rest api to transfer flowfiles to an input port. I was going through the NiFi rest api docs and found that there seems to be support to achieve the same. However, it is not very clear or detailed to be honest.

My workflow goes like this:
**Parent Level View**
[image]

**Inside Source processor group:**
[image]

**Inside Destination processor group:**
[image]

What I want to know is how can I transfer the flow files queued up from the source processor group to the destination processor group's input port so that it can be stored using `PutFile`.

I wanted to try to hit this endpoint:
`http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/data-transfer/input-ports/{portId}/transactions/{transactionId}/flow-files`

Although I can get the portId from the input port, I don't know what the transactionID is and from where I can get that.

**Note**: I know I can do this using the NiFi's web UI but I want to know how to accomplish the same using NiFi's REST API.

Comment: If they are in the same NiFi, you can directly connect an output port on one Process Group to the input port on another Process Group (connecting the PG boxes in your Parent View).  Do you need to use the API?

Comment: I know we can do this with the NiFi web UI. I want to accomplish the same using NiFi API.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use those endpoints to create the transaction. Here's the link to a spot in the source where NiFi communicates with these endpoints [1] using the Site-To-Site client library. It's not a simple call to send a flowfile, as you'll need to create the transaction, send the content, confirm the transaction, and then complete it.

[1] https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-site-to-site-reporting-bundle/nifi-site-to-site-reporting-task/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/reporting/SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask.java#L206

Comment: That makes sense but can you be a bit more specific? I'm going to stick with the REST API endpoints so please tell me how to create a transaction first. I mean which endpoint from the Data Transfer APIs should I use?